# Forge Viewer Cut model Level Wise

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am using viewer 7.* and I wanted to cut the model so that I only get to see a level.
i.e. If I select  level 1 as lower bound and level 2 as upper bound I only get level 1 element in the viewer.

I am able to retrieve level information from aec data.

Please Help me with this.

Comment: Please provide some code you tried yourself !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set cut planes by levels, please check my example here: https://github.com/yiskang/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/nodejs-level-sectioning/public/js/AdnLevelSectionPanel.js

And check this PDF which illustrates the sectioning concept: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/blob/master/level-section/docs/Forge%20Viewer%20Sectioning.pdf

BTW, you can also load the `Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension` directly to view the model by levels.(required AecModelData for Revit 2018 and later)

Hope it helps